# Combine layer chrominance with image luminance

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have read this [Colorization paper](http://hi.cs.waseda.ac.jp/~iizuka/projects/colorization/data/colorization_sig2016.pdf) and it said:

> The output layer of the colorization network consists of a
>   convolutional layer with a Sigmoid transfer function that outputs the
>   chrominance of the input grayscale image.

and in order to get the colored image they said:

> the computed chrominance is combined with the input intensity image to
>   produce the resulting color image.

So I have implemented it and get the output layer with depth two, but how can I get the color image? How can I combine the greyscale image luminance values with the output layer of depth 2 (a*b colors) to get the final image?

I use tensorflow and python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried to implement it by using **Skimage** library to make a tensor of image chrominance values and compine it with the luminance by the same method.